# Solution for WPF/Wacom compatibility problems, or can I disable WPF tablet support?

Tags: wpf, wacom

I sell a WPF (.net 3.5SP1) based time tracking application, this application has no tablet/pen/ink related features what so ever.

I have a compatibility problem with Wacom tablets, on computers with a Wacom tablet my application may freeze, crush or, in the latest case - override the user's tablet settings (but not on every computer with a Wacom tablet, some do work, at least part of the time).

In that latest case the problem seems to be that starting my application will also start wisptis.exe (Microsoft Pen and Touch Input Component), killing this process solves the problem.

Does anyone knows how to make WPF co-exist peacefully with Wacom tablets?

Again, my app does not have any pen features what so ever, so completely turning off WPF pen support to avoid conflicts can solve my problem.

I don't want my app to effect any other app on the system, so uninstalling Windows components, changing global machine-level settings or changing the Wacom drivers (except to the latest version) are not an option.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There's a few dependency properties you can explore

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Stylus.SetIsTapFeedbackEnabled(this, false);
        Stylus.SetIsPressAndHoldEnabled(this, false);
        Stylus.SetIsTouchFeedbackEnabled(this, false);

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

These can be used in Windows 8 to disable 'bubbles' in your own application.

Still looking for a way to disable 'bubbles' in Visual Studio.